# Problem using CriteriaBuilder's isMember method with Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

When using the isMember method of CriteriaBuilder with Kotlin in my application it gives me the following error in the following line:

[image]

I've been researching and they always use that form to add a predicate to filter when they need to filter on a list of entity elements.

Do you know what could be happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Content_`-like classes are generated from corresponding `@Entity` classes. You need to enable plugin that makes this job done during build. With Maven it could be done like following:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

After rebuild `Content_` (and all similar classes) should appear on classpath